# drive ws2812b using avr timer, fast pwm and interrupts

Tags: c, timer, embedded, interrupt, avr

Before anyone shouts at me, I know the WS2812B LED strips demand a very precise timing and that it is more easily done with assembly code (and that great libraries already exist out there).

Still, I'm wondering: is it really not possible to drive the strips using timers and interrupts ? After all, the atmega328p doc says about timers that it "*allows accurate program execution timing (event management) and wave generation*".

I'm using an arduino nano (atmega328p) with a CPU frequency of 16MHz (so with Fast PWM, we get a cycle of duration 6.25 ns right?)

Here's what I wish to do : I want to use the Timer0 to generate the bit-banging signal to drive the LED Strip. I looked into the [light_ws2812 lib](https://github.com/cpldcpu/light_ws2812) for (working) timings and my math gave me the following:

- A short period (T0H or T1L) is 350 ns so it's about 5 timer steps;
- A long period (T1H or T0L) is 900 ns, so about 14 timer steps;

So I set up the timer0 to mode 7 according to the Atmega328p datasheet: Fast PWM mode, with a TOP limit of 14+5=19 defined by OCR0A, and I set a compare match value of either 5 or 14 in OCR0B depending on the bit value to be sent. The change of value in OCR0B is done with interrupt on counter overflow flag

A first try is to light one led in color red ; I wrote the following code to achieve all this :

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


#define T0H_t 5
#define T1H_t 14
#define TOTAL_t (T0H_t+T1H_t)

#define GET_TIME(B) (B & 1? T1H_t : T0H_t)

#define MAX_LEDS 10
#define BUFFER_SIZE (3*MAX_LEDS)


/**
 * @brief Buffer for GRB values to be sent via bit-banging.
 * 
 * Bytes are sent in MSBF. When all bytes are sent, buffer should get reset.
 */
struct sending_buffer 
{
    uint8_t buffer [BUFFER_SIZE];   // stores RGB bytes to be sent

    uint8_t byte_index;             // index to byte being sent
    uint8_t bit_index;              // index to next bit to be sent
    uint8_t last_byte;              // index of last byte + 1
};

struct sending_buffer colors_to_send;


struct sending_buffer * init_buffer(struct sending_buffer * sb)
{
    sb->byte_index = 0;
    sb->bit_index = 7;
    sb->last_byte = 0;

    return sb;
}

// returns the bit value of next bit to be sent from sb
uint8_t get_next_bit(struct sending_buffer * sb)
{
    uint8_t bit = (sb->buffer[sb->byte_index] >> sb->bit_index--) & 1;

    sb->bit_index = sb->bit_index > 7 ? 7 : sb->bit_index ; // Bytes are sent in MSBF
    if(sb->bit_index == 7) 
    {
        sb->byte_index++;
        sb->byte_index %= BUFFER_SIZE;
    }

    return bit;
}

uint8_t put_byte(struct sending_buffer * sb, uint8_t byte)
{
    sb->buffer[sb->last_byte++] = byte;
}

uint8_t send_color(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
{
    put_byte(&colors_to_send, g);
    put_byte(&colors_to_send, r);
    put_byte(&colors_to_send, b);
}

void init_send()
{
    if(colors_to_send.byte_index < colors_to_send.last_byte)
    {
        uint8_t next_bit = get_next_bit(&colors_to_send);
        OCR0B = GET_TIME(next_bit);
    }
    sei();
}

void setup_interrupt()
{
    /**
     * @brief Setting up Fast PWM mode with TOP value defined by OCR0A ; clearing OC0B on c-m between OCR0B and TCNT0.
     * 
     */

    // Set Fast PWM mode with TOP value defined by OCR0A
    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM00) | (1 << WGM01);
    TCCR0B |= (1 << WGM02);

    // Set COM0B1 to clear OC0B on compare match
    TCCR0A |= (1 << COM0B1);

    // Set timer without prescaler (CS00)
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00);

    // Set TOP value
    OCR0A = TOTAL_t; // Assuming TOTAL_t is correctly calculated elsewhere

    // Set initial value of OCR0B to 0 (clear OC0B)
    OCR0B = 0;

    // Set pin 5 (OC0B) as output
    DDRD |= (1 << PD5);

    // Enable interrups
    TIMSK0 |= (1 << TOIE0);
}


ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    if(colors_to_send.byte_index < colors_to_send.last_byte)
    {
        uint8_t next_bit = get_next_bit(&colors_to_send);
        OCR0B = GET_TIME(next_bit);
    }
}

int main()
{
    _delay_ms(10);
    init_buffer(&colors_to_send);

    send_color(255,0,0);

    setup_interrupt();
    init_send();
    while(colors_to_send.byte_index < colors_to_send.last_byte)
    ;
    cli();
    OCR0B = 0;
    _delay_ms(10);

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Now obvisously I'm doing something wrong since this is not working. So my question is:

Is my code wrong in some place (and if it is, where?), or is it really undoable to drive the WS2812B that way?

Comment: Do you know how many instruction cycles single ISR call takes? However there are implementations on ARM using DMA and timers. There are also implementations that sends one LED and then it can stall some time but no more than the reset signal normaly takes

Comment: Btw: 6.25ns is 160 000 000 Hz not 16 MHz

Comment: The best tool to investigate is an oscilloscope or logic analyzer. If you are developing such "delicate" timings, you need it to check the correct output signals. Please [edit] your question to add your measurements.

Comment: Atmega328p is likely way too crappy for nanosecond accuracy. Interrupt latency aside, have you looked at the latency in the port hardware itself? Consider using a modern MCU if you need that kind of resolution. Or otherwise look into what output features the timer module got, can it be set to toggle on some condition other than software?

Answer (score 0):

You have 1.25 microseconds to send one bit. That's 20 clock cycles. From this, 4 cycles to activate the interrupt (`CALL` instruction) and 4 cycles to return from interrupt (`RETI` instruction) must be substracted. You have 12 machine cycles left. Do you think the interrupt handler code you created only has 12 instructions?
In my opinion, this cannot be done even in assembler. In C no way. And I agree with the comments. Measure it yourself. There is nothing simpler. If you want to do such things on the edge, you must also have the appropriate equipment (logic analyzer or oscilloscope).